# Approach to convert from org.joda.time.DateTime to java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Anyone done this and can share? I see an option or two but want to know what others have accomplished.

Answer (score 26):

According to joda-time documentation the preferred method to use is to call this:
[AbstractDateTime#toCalendar](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toCalendar(java.util.Locale)).

Answer (score 13):

You can also call AbstractInstant#toDate

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate()

Comment: Which is most easily accesible as DateTime.toDate()

Comment: ...and returns a Date, not a Calendar.  Esko's response is right on though.

Answer (score 1):

in the 2.1 you can use

```
public static Calendar parseCalendar(DateTime dt){
    return dt.toGregorianCalendar();
}
```