# How do I convert a org.joda.time.LocalDateTime into java.Util.Calendar?

Tags: java, jodatime

The question is in the heading really. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: And uhm, why do you want to do this? Interoperability reasons?

Comment: @fge Yes, I use joda for handling time and date in general but need to use a lib which requires a Calendar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime jodaTime = LocalDateTime.now();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(jodaTime.toDate());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use toCalendar

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toCalendar%28java.util.Locale%29

Here is a post [Approach to convert from org.joda.time.DateTime to java.util.Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363930/approach-to-convert-from-org-joda-time-datetime-to-java-util-calendar)

eg.

```
Date date = dateTime.toDate();
 Calendar calendar = dateTime.toCalendar(Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: That works on DateTime, but I am specifically trying to convert a LocalDateTime. Maybe it's my joda version that's old but LocalDateTime doesn't seem to have that method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this approach, LocalDateTime to Calendar of java.util:

Conversion sequence: LocalDateTime -> DateTime -> Calendar

```
    LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime();
    DateTime dt = ldt.toDateTime();
    Calendar c = dt.toCalendar(null);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Hope this one works for you. Cheers!